# How can I set the column width on a given column in multiple opened Excel files at once?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, column

I have 10 opened Excel files. Each of them contains one spreadsheet. How can I set the column width on a given column in multiple opened Excel files at once? I use Excel 2205 on Microsoft Windows 10.

Comment: Hey @Franck Dernoncourt ,,, it's rare to work on such issue,,, but yes is possible,, since U r experienced user so that is possible for u to fix it,,, what I would like to suggest ,,, first store all WBs in folder,,, then use VBA code to open each WB in LOOP in a selected folder,, use worksheet open method through array then apply new column width to particular column, Saves WB & Closes ,, the loop will do this for rest of WBs. ☺

Comment: "I use Excel 2205" Are you a time traveller !?

Comment: @DavidPostill https://mspoweruser.com/office-version-2205-for-windows-insiders/

Comment: Ah. MS wonky versioning strikes again.

Comment: @DavidPostill agreed, crap version names.